# CPPUNIT_ASSERT_THROW for std:exception

Tags: c++, unit-testing, cppunit

In the release notes for CppUnit 1.11.4 it states:

> Notes: change made to CPPUNIT_ASSERT_THROW may cause compilation error if you're expecting std::exception as it would be caught twice. Contact us if it is an issue (we don't see much use for such a test).

Can someone please explain why such a test is not useful?